# PHP how to keep checkbox array checked after submitting

Tags: php

It seems like a solved problem but I've done through research on this for hours but all the solutions that I tried didn't work for me. Please help me I am 
imploding and tired...I'd like to keep ONLY the checked ones checked after submitting the form or if any errors occur. 
Here is my problem.

```
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="pepperoni" id="top1"><label 
for="top1">Pepperoni</label>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="bacon" id="top2"><label 
for="top2">Canadian Bacon</label>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="sausage" id="top3"><label 
for="top3">Sausage</label>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="mushrooms" id="top4"><label 
for="top4">Mushrooms</label>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="pineapple" id="top5"><label 
for="top5">Pineapple</label>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="peppers" id="top6"><label 
for="top6">Peppers</label>
```

And This is what I tried

```
$toppingArr=array();
if(!empty($_GET["toppings"]))
    {
            foreach($_GET['toppings'] as $tops)
        {
            array_push($toppingArr,$tops);
        }
    }
<input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="pepperoni" id="top1"
            <?= (in_array("pepperoni", $toppingArr)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
            <label for="top1">Pepperoni</label>
            <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="bacon" id="top2"
            <?= (in_array("bacon", $toppingArr)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
            <label for="top2">Canadian Bacon</label>
            <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="sausage" id="top3">
            <?= (in_array("sausage", $toppingArr)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
            <label for="top3">Sausage</label>
            <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="mushrooms" id="top4"
            <?= (in_array("mushrooms", $toppingArr)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
            <label for="top4">Mushrooms</label>
            <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="pineapple" id="top5"
            <?= (in_array("pineapple", $toppingArr)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
            <label for="top5">Pineapple</label>
            <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="peppers" id="top6"
            <?= (in_array("peppers", $toppingArr)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
            <label for="top6">Peppers</label>
```

Comment: My solution is if checkbox not empty make a cookie then read cookie if exist check checkbox

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `>` at `id="top3">` preventing your code from working properly. It  should be reading `id="top3"`.

With the error corrected, your code could work when you are posting on the same page. If you are moving away from the page and coming back, you would use `$_SESSION` variables instead of `$_GET`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $toppingArr=array();
      if(!empty($_GET["toppings"]))
      {
          foreach($_GET['toppings'] as $tops)
          {
              array_push($toppingArr,$tops);
          }
      }
    ?>
    <form>
      <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="pepperoni" id="top1" <?php if(in_array('pepperoni', $toppingArr)) echo 'checked'; ?> ><label
      for="top1">Pepperoni</label>
      <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="bacon" id="top2" <?php if(in_array('bacon', $toppingArr)) echo 'checked'; ?>><label
      for="top2">Canadian Bacon</label>
      <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="sausage" id="top3" <?php if(in_array('sausage', $toppingArr)) echo 'checked'; ?>><label
      for="top3">Sausage</label>
      <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="mushrooms" id="top4" <?php if(in_array('mushrooms', $toppingArr)) echo 'checked'; ?>><label
      for="top4">Mushrooms</label>
      <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="pineapple" id="top5" <?php if(in_array('pineapple', $toppingArr)) echo 'checked'; ?>><label
      for="top5">Pineapple</label>
      <input name="toppings[]" type="checkbox" value="peppers" id="top6" <?php if(in_array('peppers', $toppingArr)) echo 'checked'; ?>><label
      for="top6">Peppers</label>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest I really appreciate it. but .. it still doens't work and It loses data after submitting the form

Comment: It seems its working fine. I don't know what are you talking about. After submission it retains the value whatever you have selected.